# Miniconda Not Using Environment Python

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda, anaconda3

I've searched for hours - if this is a duplicate question please be kind :)

PC had Anaconda 4.x.x.  Resolver took hours and I was stuck, could not upgrade Anaconda.  Therefore I:

- Uninstalled Anaconda
- Downloaded Miniconda for Windows 10
- Created a new environment, installed pandas 1.5.2.

The top of my python file looks like this:

```
print('Top of file')
import pandas as pd
```

I activate my new environment and execute program.
Prompt returns:

> Top of file

> File "E:\MyPath\first_take.py", line 2, in 
> import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

When I use `conda list` in the environment I see `pandas 1.5.2` in the results.

This is where I've been chasing my tail for hours.

I've tried:

- Setting PATH variable to include folders where python.exe and pip are located.
- Reinstalling Miniconda and letting it set my PATH variable.
- Recreating the environment and calling out a specific python version.
- Setting default program to open .py files as Python.

UPDATE 1:
I opened VS Code and had the same issue.  However, I was able to change my Python interpreter to the one in the miniconda folder.

Confirms my belief the interpreter being used from Anaconda prompt is not the one I think it is, and don't know how to change it.

Update 2:

```
(minitab) C:\Users\Drew>where conda
C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat
C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

(minitab) C:\Users\Drew>where python
C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\envs\minitab\python.exe
C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\python.exe
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Have you activated your environment yet?

Comment: Yes, I have.  I deactivated and reactivated it several times.  I also deactivated the base environment as some said that made a difference.   Didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm little familiar with Windows, but I think the Windows equivalent of the *nix `which` command is `where`. Try `where conda` and `where python`, and see if the paths roughly match. Moreover, `where python` should show a path that leads to the active Conda environment.

Comment: @9769953 - thanks for trying to help, included results in Update 2 above - the paths appear to match.

Comment: Odd. Funny though how `python.exe` is not inside a `bin` folder (like it would be on *nix). Could try and locate the `pandas` folder inside `C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\envs\minitab`. It should be somewhere in `C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\envs\minitab\lib\python3.?\site-packages` (question mark for the minor version of Python, and `lib` possibly optional. Not even sure about `site-packages` under Windows now).